# Refactor a coroutine in Python

Tags: python, refactoring, coroutine

I want to refactor a coroutine by moving some of its code in another function/coroutine. But I would need to retrieve its last feed in the containing coroutine, and I've got no idea how to properly do that.

Here's an example with a simpler coroutine.

```py
def coroutine():
    """Yield a string containing the number sent. If 5 is sent, block for 5 turns."""
    feed = yield 0
    while True:
        if feed == 5:
            for i in range(5, 0, -1):
                feed = yield f"Blocked for {i} turns"
        feed = yield f"Received {feed}"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_coroutine = coroutine()
    next(my_coroutine)  # Init the coroutine

    # Print the coroutine results for inputs from 0 to 14
    for j in range(15):
        print(f"{j} -> {my_coroutine.send(j)}")
```

The result that I expect (and get) is

```
0 -> Received 0
1 -> Received 1
2 -> Received 2
3 -> Received 3
4 -> Received 4
5 -> Blocked for 5 turns
6 -> Blocked for 4 turns
7 -> Blocked for 3 turns
8 -> Blocked for 2 turns
9 -> Blocked for 1 turns
10 -> Received 10
11 -> Received 11
12 -> Received 12
13 -> Received 13
14 -> Received 14
```

Now, I want to improve my code by moving the reusable part to a coroutine `wait_for_five_turns` :

```py
def wait_for_five_turns():
    """Block for 5 turns."""
    for i in range(5, 0, -1):
        feed = yield f"Blocked for {i} turns"


def coroutine():
    """Yield a string containing the number sent. If 5 is sent, block for 5 turns."""
    feed = yield 0
    while True:
        if feed == 5:
            yield from wait_for_five_turns()
        # "feed" is not up to date ! And it's logic, but bothersome.
        feed = yield f"Received {feed}"
```

```
0 -> Received 0
1 -> Received 1
2 -> Received 2
3 -> Received 3
4 -> Received 4
5 -> Blocked for 5 turns
6 -> Blocked for 4 turns
7 -> Blocked for 3 turns
8 -> Blocked for 2 turns
9 -> Blocked for 1 turns
10 -> Received 5  <----- Not what I want
11 -> Received 11
12 -> Received 12
13 -> Received 13
14 -> Received 14
```

Is there a way to retrieve the correct value of feed ?
Or maybe a better way to refactor ?
Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It possible to also return a value from a coroutine. In the the current example, this will be :

```py
def wait_for_five_turns():
    """Block for 5 turns."""
    for i in range(5, 0, -1):
        feed = yield f"Blocked for {i} turns"
    return feed


def coroutine():
    """Yield a string containing the number sent. If 5 is sent, block for 5 turns."""
    feed = yield 0
    while True:
        if feed == 5:
            feed = yield from wait_for_five_turns()
        feed = yield f"Received {feed}"
```

This prints the correct expected output :

```
0 -> Received 0
1 -> Received 1
2 -> Received 2
3 -> Received 3
4 -> Received 4
5 -> Blocked for 5 turns
6 -> Blocked for 4 turns
7 -> Blocked for 3 turns
8 -> Blocked for 2 turns
9 -> Blocked for 1 turns
10 -> Received 10  <-- Yeah.
11 -> Received 11
12 -> Received 12
13 -> Received 13
14 -> Received 14
```

I was using a wrong type annotation (3rd element of the Generator type hint) that made me think a coroutine could only return None.

For info, here's the type hint for those two functions :

```py
def wait_for_five_turns() -> Generator[float, str, float]: ...
def coroutine() -> Generator[float, str, float]: ...
```